# How to change back and hide my menu when other menu item was clicked?

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

The problem with my code is that I am creating a on click function which basically causes to close my most recently clicked menu object. How to perform closing of other menu items properly?

```
$("#menu-item-1").click(function() 
{
    var elem = $("#menu-content-1");
    var parent = $(this);

    if (elem.css("display") == "none")
    {
        parent.css("font-weight", "bold");

        elem.slideDown();
        elem.css("left", theLeft);
        elem.css("top", p.top + 50);
    }
    else
    {
        elem.slideUp(function() { img.hide(); });
    }


    $("#menu-item-2").click(function() { $("#menu-content-2").slideUp(function() { 
        $("#hiddenImg1").hide(); 
        $("#menu-item-2").css("font-weight", "normal"); }); });
    $("#menu-item-3").click(function() { $("#menu-content-3").slideUp(function() { 
        $("#hiddenImg1").hide(); 
        $("#menu-item-3").css("font-weight", "normal"); }); });
    $("#menu-item-4").click(function() { $("#menu-content-4").slideUp(function() { 
        $("#hiddenImg1").hide(); 
        $("#menu-item-4").css("font-weight", "normal"); }); });
    $("#menu-item-5").click(function() { $("#menu-content-5").slideUp(function() { 
        $("#hiddenImg1").hide(); 
        $("#menu-item-5").css("font-weight", "normal"); }); });
});
```

Comment: Could you provide jsfiddle link?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Comment: @Blazemonger, thank you for a tip, I'm sure this will be useful in the future. But this will not solve my problem, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I actually did was to add a handler to every button that checks where the mouse is located. Then if the mouse click is not located on the clickable container, the container will be collapsed. Perfect!

```
$("#menu-item-5").click(function() 
{
    var elem = $("#menu-content-5");
    var parent = $("#menu-item-5");
    var o = parent.offset();

    if (elem.css("display") == "none")
    {
        elem.slideDown();
        elem.css("left", (p.left + parent.width()) - elem.width() - 4);
        elem.css("top", p.top + 50);
    }
    else
    {
        elem.slideUp(function() { img.hide(); parent.css("font-weight", "normal"); });
    }

    $(window).click(function(e)
    {
        var hstart = o.left;
        var hend = o.left + parent.width();
        var vstart = o.top;
        var vend = o.top + parent.height();

        if(((e.clientX >= hstart) && (e.clientX <= hend)) && ((e.clientY >= vstart) && (e.clientY <= vend)))
        {
            //elem.slideUp(function() { img.hide(); parent.css("font-weight", "normal"); });
        }
        else
        {
            elem.slideUp(function() { img.hide(); parent.css("font-weight", "normal"); }); 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: But can someone tell me please why does this break when user resizes the browser window? LOL